# FactoryGirl belongs_to association and validates_presence_of failing -- foreign key is associated, object is not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations, factory-bot, belongs-to

After upgrading from FactoryGirl 2.5.2 to 4.5.0, validations for `belongs_to` associations fail.

The two model files:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  ...
  has_many :things
  ...
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user   
  validates_presence_of :user
  ...
end
```

The factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define
  factory :thing do
    association :user      
    ...
  end
end
```

Creating a new `thing` always fails saying `User must be provided`. When I step into the code, the problem is that the foreign key is set correctly, but the associated object appears to be nil.

```
>> user = create(:user)
  ( returns saved "user" object )
>> user.id
1
>> thing = build(:thing, user: user)
  ( returns new "thing" object )
>> thing.valid?
false
>> thing.user_id
1
>> User.find(1).present?
true
>> thing.user
nil
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations and variations on this. I've tried using `after(:build)` blocks to set the user and using different FactoryGirl syntax. I've tried just having a plain `user` instead of the association. But it always comes down to this problem -- there is an associated key, and it is correct, but not an associated object (even though that object exists and is saved).

Environment:

```
ruby 2.1.5

factory_girl 4.5.0
factory_girl_rails 4.5.0
rails 4.2.0
rspec 3.1.0
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.  It looks like my after(:build) blocks aren't even being fired - like it's failing validation before it gets to those callbacks.  Any more progress on your end?

Comment: One gotcha I noticed: the "User must be provided" was actually firing from another model whose Factory wasn't finished yet.  Assuming you simplified your example for SO you might want to check if any associated models also need a User...

Comment: I think the `factory_girl` part of this was a red herring -- but at least it made it easier to focus on exactly what was going on. The underlying problem seems to be related to Rails 4.2 itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a User factory. If you have done so, please edit your answer to show it.

Comment: Implied by the:

`>> user = create(:user)
  ( returns saved "user" object )`